# end = ' ', para que sirve, no lo tengo muy en claro

Tags: python

¿para que se usa , end = ' '? ,segun entiendo es para dejar un espacio en vez de un salto de linea . Tengo python 3.7.3

Comment: Me imagino que estás hablando del parámetro `end` en un `print()`? Sirve exactamente para hacer lo que dices, por defecto, el caracter final del print es `\n`, o sea un salto de línea. Puedes reemplazarlo por cualquier otro, con `''` simplemente no se hace el salto de línea y cada cadena impresa se muestra concatenada.

Comment: muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Además de lo explicado, el `end=""` se usa tanto para unir datos, modificar cadenas y salida.

Por ejemplo. Si escribimos:

```py
for x in range(1,5):
    print(x)
```

Esto imprimiría:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Teniendo en cuenta esto, si agregamos `print(x,end="+")`
esto imprimiría:

```
1+2+3+4+
```

Aquí `end=""` puedes modificarlo según lo que quieras para hacer modificaciones de cadena.